# XML output Print in Browser using JAVA

Tags: java, xml

Here I try to access two third party API.
I got two xml response, I merge them in one single file and store it in local system.
If i print the output in console I got the output in xml format, but I want to print it in the browser.

My solution won't work please help me.

Here's my code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws  ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String btn1=request.getParameter("btn1");
    String btn2=request.getParameter("btn2");
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
      builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    Document doc = null;
    try {
      doc = builder.parse(new URL("valid url in my program").openStream());
      response.setContentType("text/xml");
      Object con=doc.getDoctype();
    } catch (SAXException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    Document doc1 = null;
    try {
      doc1 = builder.parse(new URL(valid url).openStream());
    } catch (SAXException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("events");
    NodeList node1=doc.getElementsByTagName("events");
    Element root=doc.getDocumentElement();
    Element root1 = doc.createElement("ObjectId");
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(root1);
    root.getElementsByTagName("ObjectId").item(0).setTextContent("1");
    node1.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(root1,node1.item(0));
    NodeList nodes1 = doc1.getElementsByTagName("events");
    NodeList node2=doc1.getElementsByTagName("event");
    Element root2=doc1.getDocumentElement();
    Element root3= doc1.createElement("ObjectId");
    doc1.getDocumentElement().appendChild(root3);
    root2.getElementsByTagName("ObjectId").item(0).setTextContent("2");
    node2.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(root3,node2.item(0));
    for(int i=0;i<nodes1.getLength();i=i+1){
      Node n= (Node) doc.importNode(nodes1.item(i), true);
      nodes.item(i).getParentNode().appendChild(n);
    }
    Transformer transformer = null;
    try {
      transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    try {
      transformer.transform(source,result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Writer output = null;
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("merge.xml"));
    String xmlout = result.getWriter().toString();
    output.write(xmlout);
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    out.write(xmlout);
    //out.println(xmlout);
    //System.out.println(xmlout); 
    //I tried many ways but 
    //it will not print to the browser in xml the format
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A point of note; you're setting the ContentType three times. It only needs setting once?

You don't appear to be returning the response, but I presume some other part of your program is handling that.

**EDITED**: the other answer that was here disappeared.

Going to need more information to work out what is going wrong. Please bear in mind that `System.out.println()` calls will not show up in the browser as they're console-specific.

Comment: i tried all changes display in above but still it retreive only text output but i want xml formatted output.i remove content type repeatation and console specific but still no response it display only text output

Comment: What are you doing with the `HttpServletResponse` object? That is where the respones data will be contained.

Comment: i post my code here i try to achieve merging two files and make it single and try to send to client side(phonegap), for that i have send xml file that what i print in browser to send client(phonegap)

Comment: You're not setting the response in `HttpServletResponse`. You're not using it at all. You seem to be writing to merge.xml but you're not using it?

I'm struggling to see the scope of your project - what is this method being used for?